# Showing a div that displays drop-down content on list item click using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

```html
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang=""> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang=""> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang=""> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html class="no-js" lang="">
<!--<![endif]-->

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <title></title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="apple-touch-icon.png">

  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <style>
    body {
      padding-top: 50px;
      padding-bottom: 20px;
    }
  </style>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <!--[if lt IE 8]>
            <p class="browserupgrade">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
        <![endif]-->


  <!--MAIN CONTENT GOES HERE -->

  <style>
    /* main menu */
    .mainNav {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      min-height: 100px;
      text-align: left;
      white-space: normal;
      width: 368px;
      display: block;
      cursor: default;
    }
    .mainNav-item {
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: top;
    }
    .mainNav-item a {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: black;
    }
    .mainNav-item a:hover {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: black;
    }
    .mainNav-item-tile {
      display: block;
      margin: 6px 5px 6px 5px;
      padding: 0;
      text-align: center;
      line-height: normal;
      position: relative;
      text-decoration: none;
      width: 110px;
      height: 110px;
      background: transparent;
      border-width: 0;
      font-size: 14px;
      outline-color: #e7e7e7;
      background-color: #e7e7e7;
    }
    .mainNav-item-tile:hover {
      outline-color: #ccc;
      background-color: #ccc;
    }
    .mainNav-item-tile-img {
      display: block;
      padding: 15px;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
    }
    .popover {
      max-width: 600px;
      width: auto;
    }
    /* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
    .dropdown {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    /* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
    .dropdown-content {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #f9f9f9;
      min-width: 160px;
      box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      z-index: 1000;
      left: 80px;
      top: 20px;
    }
    /* Links inside the dropdown */
    .dropdown-content a {
      color: black;
      padding: 12px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
    }
    /* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
    .dropdown-content a:hover {
      background-color: #f1f1f1
    }
  </style>



  <div style="float: left; cursor: pointer; margin: 13px 15px 0 0">
    <img data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" onmouseover="this.src='http://placehold.it/32x32'" onmousedown="this.src='http://placehold.it/32x32'" onmouseout="this.src='http://placehold.it/32x32'" src="http://placehold.it/32x32" />

    <div id="popover_content_wrapper" style="display: none;">
      <div>
        <ul class="mainNav">
          <li class="mainNav-item dropdown" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom">
            <a ID="navItem" runat="server" class="mainNav-item-tile">
              <img width="64" height="64" src="http://placehold.it/64x64" class="mainNav-item-tile-img" />
              <span>MainMenuItem1</span>
            </a>

            <div id='content1' class='dropdown-content'>
              <a href='#'>SubMenuItem1</a>
              <a href='#'>SubMenuItem2</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="mainNav-item dropdown" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom">
            <a ID="navItem" runat="server" class="mainNav-item-tile">
              <img width="64" height="64" src="http://placehold.it/64x64" class="mainNav-item-tile-img" />
              <span>MainMenuItem2</span>
            </a>

            <div id='content2' class='dropdown-content'>
              <a href='#'>SubMenuItem1</a>
              <a href='#'>SubMenuItem2</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="mainNav-item dropdown" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom">
            <a ID="navItem" runat="server" class="mainNav-item-tile">
              <img width="64" height="64" src="http://placehold.it/64x64" class="mainNav-item-tile-img" />
              <span>MainMenuItem3</span>
            </a>

            <div id='content3' class='dropdown-content'>
              <a href='#'>SubMenuItem1</a>
              <a href='#'>SubMenuItem2</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="mainNav-item dropdown" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom">
            <a ID="navItem" runat="server" class="mainNav-item-tile">
              <img width="64" height="64" src="http://placehold.it/64x64" class="mainNav-item-tile-img" />
              <span>MainMenuItem4</span>
            </a>

            <div id='content4' class='dropdown-content'>
              <a href='#'>SubMenuItem1</a>
              <a href='#'>SubMenuItem2</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="mainNav-item dropdown" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom">
            <a ID="navItem" runat="server" class="mainNav-item-tile">
              <img width="64" height="64" src="http://placehold.it/64x64" class="mainNav-item-tile-img" />
              <span>MainMenuItem5</span>
            </a>

            <div id='content5' class='dropdown-content'>
              <a href='#'>SubMenuItem1</a>
              <a href='#'>SubMenuItem2</a>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>





  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
        html: true,
        content: function() {
          return $('#popover_content_wrapper').html();
        }
      });

      $('html').on('click', function(e) {
        $('[data-toggle="popover"]').each(function() {
          //the 'is' for buttons that trigger popups
          //the 'has' for icons within a button that triggers a popup
          if (!$(this).is(e.target) && $(this).has(e.target).length === 0 && $('.popover').has(e.target).length === 0) {
            $(this).popover('hide');
          }
        });
      });


      $(".dropdown").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this).children(".dropdown-content");
        $(".dropdown-content:visible").not($this).slideToggle(200); //Close submenu already opened
        $this.slideToggle(200); //Open the new submenu
      });
    });
  </script>


</body>

</html>
```

My goal here is to show the drop-down content when one of the li items is clicked. I am using this [example on w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_dropdowns.asp) as a basis. The only problem with this example is that it displays the dropdown-content on hover.

Now I am trying to figure out how to make the dropdown-content div show when an li item with the class of 'dropdown' is clicked rather than using the hover pseudo class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you need the same submenu for all your items. So first, you have to properly structure your html to have a submenu for each element. Then you can simply create your drop-down effect with jQuery and a click event.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".dropdown").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this).children(".dropdown-content");
        $(".dropdown-content:visible").not($this).slideToggle(200); //Close submenu already opened
        $this.slideToggle(200); //Open the new submenu
    });
});
```

```css
nav ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

nav ul li {
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
}

nav ul li a {
  color: #fff;
  background: #28AADC;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  display: block;
  width: 80px;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  background: #00648C;
}

ul.dropdown-content {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#">Nav 1</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-content">
                <li><a href="#">Nav 1.1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Nav 1.2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Nav 1.3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Nav 1.4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#">Nav 2</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-content">
                <li><a href="#">Nav 2.1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Nav 2.2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Nav 2.3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Nav 2.4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#">Nav 3</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-content">
                <li><a href="#">Nav 3.1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Nav 3.2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Nav 3.3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Nav 3.4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the response however when I tried to apply it I do not get any submenu popups. Can you please take a look at my exact code snippet that I added to my post and tell me what I might be doing wrong? You will notice that when you click the initial image it will open up a menu with all of the primary nav items and then when you click one of those items I would like the submenu drop-down to appear but it isn't.

Comment: It doesn't work because you significantly modify your code compared to your initial question. With your new code, you must use an onclick event for your submenu popups. So, replace this line `$(".dropdown").click(function(e){`  with this `$("html").on("click", ".dropdown", function(e) {`

Comment: .click() event only works for elements that are present on load. This is why you need to use .on() with your popup.

Comment: I apologize for changing my initial question too much. Thank you very much! it works perfectly now. You went above and beyond to help me with this one even making the assumption that each subitem would need different content.

Comment: No worries @BlakeRivell. Glad I helped.

Comment: I am sorry, but wondering if you can give me advice on one final thing. For the tiles that do not have sub-items I would like it to still navigate the user to the correct page and in this case preventdefault is stopping it I believe.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101942/discussion-between-blake-rivell-and-smdsgn).

Answer (score 2):

Your `.dropdown-content` should be a child of `.primaryNav-item.dropdown` this will allow you to use jQuery's click method to reference the parent that was clicked by the `this` variable to toggle (or [slide toggle](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/)) the `.dropdown-content` children.

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <a class="navItem">Dropdown</a>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>

$(".dropdown").click(function() {    
  $(".dropdown-content", this).stop().slideToggle();
});
```

Here is a working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/dqg1s9vm/38/
The stop method prevents from overloading the toggle functionality.

Comment: Any chance you can take a look at my code snippet and see what I might be doing wrong. I am getting no dropdown when clicking the li items.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do something like this:

```
<div class="dropdown-content" onclick="ShowMe();">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function ShowMe() { 
    document.getElementByClassName("dropdown-content").style.display = 'block';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For that, you'll have to show it using JavaScript code rather than just CSS. You included jQuery in your tags, so I'll assume it's okay to give example code that uses it.

```
$(".dropdown").click(function() {
    $(this).children(".dropdown-content").show();
});
```

This code says that, when a dropdown element is clicked, find the dropdown-content element inside it, and unhide it.

Answer (score 0):

Using JavaScript is the way to go here. For instance, the following code would suit your purpose:

```
$(document).on("click", ".dropdown-content", function() { 
     $(this).children(".dropdown-content").show(); 
}
```

You could then add a second class or attribute so that you know it's being shown. If that attribute exists and you click it again, you could hide it with .hide() and remove the class or attribute.

I hope that helps!